# How to show the default Option Value in the HTML Select Tag

Tags: jquery, html

I am appending dynamic values to the HTML Select .

I am doing it this way

```
var response = {
    "companies": [{
        "companyID": 2,
        "companyName": "RAvi Corporation Ltd."
    }, {
        "companyID": 3,
        "companyName": "Kiran Cement Ltd."
    }, {
        "companyID": 4,
        "companyName": "ACC Ltd."
    }]
}

var companies = '<option value="">All Companies</option>';
for (var i = 0; i < response.companies.length; i++) {
    companies += '<option value="' + response.companies[i].companyID + '" selected>' + response.companies[i].companyName + '</option>'
}
$("#companieslist").html(companies);
```

The last value is being shown in the HTML Select , is it possible to show All Companies as the first value ??

This is my jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/cf7hnvcq/1/

Could you please let me know how to do this

Answer (score 3):

Only the option you want to see by default should have the `selected` attribute.

Line 20 should be:

```
var companies = '<option value="" selected>All Companies</option>';
```

and line 22 should be:

```
companies += '<option value="' + response.companies[i].companyID + '">' + response.companies[i].companyName + '</option>'
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jewapuh6/)

Comment: For full browser support, give the selected attribute also a value of selected, like so `selected="selected"`

Comment: `selected` is not needed on the first `option`.

Comment: @Tushar true, but adding it explicitly makes it clearer.

Comment: @Tushar if you update the code in the future and change the order of creation, an other option will be selected by default. Better to make it explicit and do it manually.

Comment: @JustusRomijn But mostly we keep the default option as the first option. So, no that case will never happen. Right?

Comment: @Tushar I did not understand the original question like that. It looked like he wanted a specific option to be selected by default. Anyway, he should get it fixed now anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Set the value of `select` to empty. This will set the default value to the dropdown.

```
$('#companieslist').val('');
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/cf7hnvcq/2/)

OR, You can remove the `selected` attribute of `option` from the `for` loop. This will set the first `option` as selected.

```js
var response = {
  "companies": [{
    "companyID": 2,
    "companyName": "RAvi Corporation Ltd."
  }, {
    "companyID": 3,
    "companyName": "Kiran Cement Ltd."
  }, {
    "companyID": 4,
    "companyName": "ACC Ltd."
  }]
};


var companies = '<option value="">All Companies</option>';
for (var i = 0; i < response.companies.length; i++) {
  companies += '<option value="' + response.companies[i].companyID + '">' + response.companies[i].companyName + '</option>'; // Remove selected attribute from here
}
$("#companieslist").html(companies);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="companieslist" name="companieslist"></select>
</div>
```